# How to write XML in a string?

Tags: xml, c#-4.0

I do not have right to write on a disk. I want to create a `string` which consist of `xml` file.

I do not want to give filename because I have no permissions. If I simply append `xml` to `string` is it working? Is there any better way to do it.

`XmlTextWriter xmlWriter = new XmlTextWriter(fileName, Encoding.UTF8);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Code Input :***

```
var rss = new XElement("rss", new XAttribute("version", "2.0"));
var channel = new XElement("channel",
    new XElement("title", "Liftoff News"),
    new XElement("link", "http://liftoff.msfc.nasa.gov/"),
    new XElement("description", "Liftoff to Space Exploration.")
    );
rss.Add(channel);
channel.Add(new XElement("item",
    new XElement("title", "Star City"),
    new XElement("link", "http://liftoff.msfc.nasa.gov/news/2003/news-starcity.asp"),
    new XElement("description", @"
        How do Americans get ready to work with Russians aboard the
        International Space Station? They take a crash course in culture, language
        and protocol at Russia's Star City.
        "),
    new XElement("pubDate", DateTime.UtcNow),
    new XElement("guid", "http://liftoff.msfc.nasa.gov/2003/06/03.html#item573")
));

var text = rss.ToString();
```

***Text Output:***

```
<rss version="2.0">
  <channel>
    <title>Liftoff News</title>
    <link>http://liftoff.msfc.nasa.gov/</link>
    <description>Liftoff to Space Exploration.</description>
    <item>
      <title>Star City</title>
      <link>http://liftoff.msfc.nasa.gov/news/2003/news-starcity.asp</link>
      <description>
          How do Americans get ready to work with Russians aboard the
          International Space Station? They take a crash course in culture, language
          and protocol at Russia's Star City.
      </description>
      <pubDate>2012-05-30T10:21:14.014Z</pubDate>
      <guid>http://liftoff.msfc.nasa.gov/2003/06/03.html#item573</guid>
    </item>
  </channel>
</rss>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
XmlDocument myDocument = new XmlDocument();

myDocument.Load("XML STRING GOES HERE");

Do the manipulation of your xml document here

string output = myDocument.InnerXml //to get to the raw Xml string.
```

An example of the DOM manipulation from the MS documentation:

```
XmlElement elem = doc.CreateElement("price");
XmlText text = doc.CreateTextNode("19.95");
doc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(elem);
doc.DocumentElement.LastChild.AppendChild(text);
```

You may create elements, nodes and attributes at will.

Comment: I need to write tags and values in xml. Is it working for xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("ChartSetting"); or                     xmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("ChartName", value);

Comment: From the Microsoft documentation       XmlElement elem = doc.CreateElement("price");
    XmlText text = doc.CreateTextNode("19.95");
    doc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(elem);
    doc.DocumentElement.LastChild.AppendChild(text);